# Android Cursor select parameter for SMS DB querying

Tags: android, select, sms, cursor

I am trying to get all SMSes from and to a single address.

So while using a Cursor to scan the DB, I tried to use select. But, no values were returned. I suspect that this was caused because the numbers in the "address" colum in the DB were containing space and/or hyphens (-).

My question is that can I make a query to ignore spaces and hyphens in the string?

P.S.: the address I have has been trimmed down to not include spaces and hyphens, and that is unchangeable as per my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation and tried below method.(not yet sure,was it a proper solution or not! :) )

So,

- Query all conversations from conversation table
- take a loop and go through all results.For each:

  - take the address field and remove unwanted character to make it like the number format you have
  - compare with number you want conversation for : if found => break
- you will have the thread-id for the number you are searching sms of,at the end of loop.

Now,

- now collect message id of all messages under that thread seperated by type:"sent" and "inbox"

Then you can use those array of id to gather messages from "sent" and "inbox" table of ContentProvider.

I know,the process is bit longer but gave me satisfactory result. :) Hope it helps.

Comment: i have done the same. i have shortened it by passing a cursor through content://sms rather than content"//sms/inbox etc. so as to get all results.

My main concern is that when there are loads of SMSes in the DB, will scanning ALL the SMSes make things significantly slower? So, going to check it out on a larger SMS DB on a friend's phone or something, as i just delete msgs to keep the apps fast enough :-) !

Comment: @Daksh: you are right..it might get the app slower in performance sometime. But no other solution on mind till now!